# Cannot find namespace 'amp'

Tags: typescript, azure, namespaces, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am writing a React/TypeScript project that uses Azure Media Player. Per the [docs](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/) under Referencing the Player, I should be able to reference the player like this:

```
var myPlayer = amp('vid1');
```

I then get a compiler error:

```
TypeScript error in C:/<file path>/<file name>.tsx(47,17):
Cannot find namespace 'amp'.  TS2503
```

I see that this is a TypeScript error, but the docs are written for JavaScript.

So I try TypeScript:

```
let player: amp.Player = amp("player");
```

Same compiler error.

**How do I reference the AMP player in my React/TypeScript project?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript complains since `amp` types needs to be imported first. According to [this thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169396-azure-media-services/suggestions/18872890-add-npm-package-for-amp-with-typescript-definition) npm package for Azure Media Player with TypeScript definitions is not available yet. But since definitions [are available](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/azuremediaplayer.d.ts) from CDN, here is an example how to add *custom* typings to project:

a) download `azuremediaplayer.d.ts` definitions and place it under `src` directory, for example in separate folder `amp_typings`:

```
amp_typings
    |
    azuremediaplayer.d.ts
```

b) add a reference to this type definitions in the `compilerOptions` section of your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "amp_typings"]
  },
  ...
}
```

That's it, now `amp` module could be used in React app.

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9jegrq)

Comment: From where would I download the file?

Comment: @SuperJade, there you go [TypeScript Definitions (d.ts)](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/azuremediaplayer.d.ts) (from [docs](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/))